# Linked List printing problems:

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
      int value;
      struct Node *next;
}Node;


Node *create_node(int value){
  Node *p=malloc(sizeof(Node));
  p->value=value;
  p->next=NULL;
  return p;
}

void *insert_at_head(Node **head,Node *node){
  node->next=*head;
  *head=node;
}

void insert_after_node(Node *node_to_insert_after,Node *new_node){
  new_node->next=node_to_insert_after->next;
  node_to_insert_after->next=new_node;
}

void printlist(Node *head){
  Node *tmp=head;
  while(tmp!=NULL){
    printf(" %d",tmp->value);
    tmp=tmp->next;
  }
}

Node *find_node(Node *head,int value){
  Node *tmp=head;
  while(tmp!=NULL){
    if(tmp->value==value) return tmp;
    tmp=tmp->next;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(){
  Node *head;
  Node *tmp;

  for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
    tmp=create_node(i);
    insert_at_head(&head,tmp);   
  }
  
  tmp=find_node(head,24);  
  insert_after_node(tmp,create_node(75));  
  printlist(head);
  
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the code it gives me 24 75 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
but when I replace `insert_after_node(tmp,create_node(75));` by `insert_after_node(head,create(75));`    it gives me 24 75 23 why?

Comment: Please do not spam tags.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask]. Lastly please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: [your code is not working at all](https://ideone.com/aMoRJR) ... you never set value to `head` ...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Both work well provided you initialise the `head` pointer:

```
Node *head = NULL;
```

Local variables are not default initialised in C.

Comment: Yes i did initialise the head to NULL

Comment: But the problem i faced is why it does not print the whole list when i put insert_after_node(head,create(75));

Comment: It does, but you never print any end of line, so everything is printed on the same line.